# Mongoose kitten example not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to get started with the kitten example at the mongoose website, but I keep getting this error saying:

> process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
>                                             ^ TypeError: undefined is not a function

My code is directly copied from the example at the website, but it will not work.

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/db');


var app = express();
var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function (callback) {

  var kittySchema = mongoose.Schema({
      name: String
  })

  var Kitten = mongoose.model('Kitten', kittySchema)

  var silence = new Kitten({ name: 'Silence' })
console.log(silence.name) // 'Silence'

// NOTE: methods must be added to the schema before compiling it with mongoose.model()
kittySchema.methods.speak = function () {
  var greeting = this.name
    ? "Meow name is " + this.name
    : "I don't have a name"
  console.log(greeting);
}

var Kitten = mongoose.model('Kitten', kittySchema)

var fluffy = new Kitten({ name: 'fluffy' });
fluffy.speak() // "Meow name is fluffy"
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('hello world');
});

app.get('/secret', function(req, res) {
  res.send('secret page');
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;

app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log('http://127.0.0.1:' + port + '/');

});
```

I'm sorry if the answer is obvious but I've just started out with Node.js and need some help getting the hang of it.

Thank you in advance.

UPDATE: The full error message

```
/Users/joseph/Documents/Atom-files/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:274
      process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
                                          ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at NativeConnection.<anonymous> (/Users/joseph/Documents/Atom-files/test/app.js:18:17)
    at NativeConnection.g (events.js:199:16)
    at NativeConnection.emit (events.js:104:17)
    at open (/Users/joseph/Documents/Atom-files/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:485:10)
    at NativeConnection.Connection.onOpen (/Users/joseph/Documents/Atom-files/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:494:5)
    at /Users/joseph/Documents/Atom-files/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:453:10
    at /Users/joseph/Documents/Atom-files/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/connection.js:59:5
    at /Users/joseph/Documents/Atom-files/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:206:5
    at connectHandler (/Users/joseph/Documents/Atom-files/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:272:7)
    at g (events.js:199:16)
    at emit (events.js:107:17)
    at /Users/joseph/Documents/Atom-files/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:374:23
    at /Users/joseph/Documents/Atom-files/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:730:13
    at Callbacks.emit (/Users/joseph/Documents/Atom-files/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:84:3)
    at null.messageHandler (/Users/joseph/Documents/Atom-files/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:219:23)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/joseph/Documents/Atom-files/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:259:22)
14 May 21:02:09 - [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: I did a similar thing but it isn't a case of  just copying each step one after the other. You have to put the code inside  the db.once('open') function and make sure you add the speak method to the schema before calling it.

Answer (score 6):

You're compiling your schema twice, and one of those times is before defining the method. This line specifically:

```
var Kitten = mongoose.model('Kitten', kittySchema)
```

You need to wait until after you've defined your `kittySchema.methods` before compiling it with `mongoose.model`. Your own code comment is telling you not to do this :)

Also, for future reference, the `TypeError: undefined is not a function` error you pasted isn't of much use but the call stack below it is, where it points out that fluffy `has no method 'speak'`.

Comment: I've tried deleting the first "mongoose.model"-line but it still won't run. Also, there is no line with "has no method 'speak'".

Comment: "still won't run" -- care to elaborate?

Comment: You probably didn't also delete the `var silence = new Kitten({ name: 'Silence' })` line that refers to a `Kitten` that doesn't exist yet. Why bother reading error messages when you could just post them all to SO?

Answer (score 0):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test', {useNewUrlParser: true});

var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
  // we're connected!`enter code here`
  var kittySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
  });

kittySchema.methods.speak = function () {
    var greeting = this.name ? "Meow name is " + this.name : "I don't have a name";
    console.log(greeting);
  }

  var Kitten = mongoose.model('Kitten', kittySchema);
  var silence = new Kitten({ name: 'Silence' });
console.log(silence.name); // 'Silence'

  var fluffy = new Kitten({ name: 'fluffy' });
   fluffy.speak(); // "Meow name is fluffy"

});
```